# Prevent HDD from being read from other machine

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I hope you can give me ideas or any recommendation on how to stop other people from reading my hdd using other pc.

Scenario:
I install ubuntu from my pc and installed nginx and php.
My goal is to run this web server and prevent someone from accessing this directory.

They can remove the HDD from my pc and use it as external drive and read the content to another machine (this is possible right?).

I want that to prevent from happening. Is this possible with ubuntu? Does encrypting the /home/user directory can prevent someone from mounting it to another machine?

Any suggestion?

[EDITS]

In case a total stranger stole my pc. I want him to be unable to read my /home folder or the disk. Unless they know what was the passphrase.

Comment: If "they" (whoever they are) have physical access to the server then "they" can do a lot more than that.

Comment: can we prevent that?  If in-case someone stole my pc. I want to prevent them from reading my hdd or certain folder

Comment: Encryption would do that if the server isn't running. If it is then it's already unencrypted and if "they" have physical access...

Comment: I see this "encrypt home directory" option on while installing. Can we prevent someone from reading our home directory then if they try mounting it to another machine?

Comment: Again, encryption was invented for that. What you still don't understand is "they" don't need to move it anywhere else if they have access to the server while it is running.

Comment: what you mean by access? having root/user account?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having problem with my english.

Comment: Basically encrypting a drive protects data at rest, e.g. while the volume is not mounted. If it's mounted, all kinds of firewire dma attacks, reboot and grabbing the memory and so on is feasible. This is essentially what secure boot from MS is supposed to fix. 

So yes, disk encryption is what you're looking for, but understand the limitations.